# Help with first Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

When my app first opens my first activity that is presented to the user can vary based on configuration options. I only know how to hard code the first activity that runs when the app is running by adding something like this in the Manifest

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MyFirstActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Where MyFirstActivity is the class name of the first activity class to be run. How can I dynamically select which activity to run first when the app is first launched rather than hard code it in the manifest?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, as my answer of not any useful so i have deleted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option #1: In `onCreate()` of `MyFirstActivity`, call `startActivity()` for the right activity, then `finish()`.

Option #2: Define several activities with the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`, all but one disabled. On first run (or as needed), enable the right activity and disable the others. Downside: may require a phone reboot to update the launcher, since not all home screen launchers will detect your change.

Option #3: Redesign your GUI such that this is not an issue.

Comment: I didn't realize you could kill activities out of order. Option 1 should work nicely for what I am trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: In my application one of two activities is chosen after the user has "registered" the application. As this only happens once, option #2 works great for me. It also has the advantage that the label and icon can also be changed.

Comment: It is simple, but may be helpful in case of Option #1, if you wouldn't like to see your `MyFirstActivity` during application set off: just make your `MyFirstActivity extends Activity` AND also put `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` in its manifest.